# Error: 405 When accessing HTML page after Form submission

Tags: html, forms, http-status-code-405

I am trying to post a dimple FORM in HTML as mentioned below:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="Home.html" onsubmit="return validateform()" >

<label class="labelText">
  Name: </label>

 <input class="textBoxName" type="text" name="name"><br/>  
 <label class="labelTextPassword"> <br/> 
 Password:</label>
 <input type="password" name="password"><br/>  
<input class="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login">  
</form>
```

Its working successfully on my SYSTEM. but when I hosted my site on Azure, after validating name and password its not re-directing to "Home" Page. It shows error
as:

The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used. (Error: 405)

Can please anyone have any idea about this issue?

Comment: `405` means `Method not allowed`. It means that `Home.html` cannot accept a `POST` request. Which makes sense, its an HTML file. You need to process your form with a server-side language.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6

Answer (score 0):

405 means Method not allowed.
It means that Home.html cannot accept a POST request
So try using the get method while sending the data and it would work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).